# In the US if there's loophole in a CFR does it go to the challenger?

Tags: united-states, common-law, civil-law, administrative-law

I was wondering if a loophole in a where a law says "must" and not "must meet all" can be used to get bend the law in your favor.

example:

> (a) Eligibility for consideration. To be eligible to apply for
>   consideration under Public Law 95-202 and this part, a group must:
>   (1) Have been similarly situated to the Women's Air Forces Service
>   Pilots of World War II.
>  (2) Have rendered service to the United
>   States in what was considered civilian employment with the U.S. Armed
>   Forces either through formal Civil Service hiring or less formal
>   hiring if the engagement was created under the exigencies of war, or
>   as the result of a contract with the U.S. Government to provide direct
>   support to the U.S. Armed Forces.
>  (3) Have rendered that service
>   during a period of armed conflict.
>  (4) Consist of living persons
>   to whom VA benefits can accrue.
>  (5) Not have already received
>   benefits from the Federal Government for the service in question.

Comment: Do you have an example of a law that says this? Words are seldom interpreted in isolation, and usually must be interpreted in the context of the statute.

Comment: Presumably what follows is a list of criteria, the penultimate one will probably end with "or" or "and". If so, this is extremely relevant.

Comment: Nope, it just has a numbered list, but I'l add that to the question..

Comment: I'm looking at the meaning of "must" vs "must meet all", and more generally the ambiguity in the language.

Comment: @acoder You can't pick words out in isolation and find ambiguity. Meaning or ambiguity of words can only be determined after reading the words in context of the entire statutory or regulatory scheme. Even if the words *are* ambiguous, the agency gets to pick any reasonable interpretation.

Comment: If that's true, why don't they need to modify the law to change it's meaning to be more strict, and therefore reduce the number of people eligible (even if it harms National Guard in this case)?

Comment: @acoder Please read Auer v. Robbins. I think it will be very helpful for understanding why the agency gets to make any reasonable interpretation of their own regulation. If the regulation is already doing all the work the agency needs it to do, then it doesn't need to rewrite it

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to [32 CFR 47.4](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/32/47.4).

The only reasonable interpretation of that list is that one must meet all of the 5 requirements.

The alternative interpretation would make any group that "[has not] already received benefits from the Federal Government for the service in question" eligible to apply.

Since this is a regulation, the interpretation of the agency that wrote the regulations is given great deference. An agency's interpretation of the regulations it writes itself is *controlling* unless "plainly erroneous or inconsistent with the regulation". (*Auer v. Robbins* 1997)

---

Regarding whether there is ambiguity at all, read *King v. Burwell* for several restatements of the principle that one must read words in context before deciding they are ambiguous:

> A provision that may seem ambiguous in isolation is often clarified by the remainder of the statutory scheme . . . because only one of the permissible meanings produces a substantive effect that is compatible with
>   the rest of the law.

They refer to the "fundamental canon of statutory construction that the
words of a statute must be read in their context and with a view to
their place in the overall statutory scheme".

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their contributions. If there is anything that can be edited into the question or answer, please do so. Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35020/discussion-on-answer-by-dawn-in-the-us-if-theres-loophole-in-a-cfr-does-it-go-t).

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretation is creating an ambiguity when none exists. Your specific question is about [32 CFR 47.4](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/32/47.4) not applying to the National Guard; however, you hone in on a single phrase while ignoring literally everything else about the regulation. So, there are additional things you look at:

- The purpose of the part. This part has a nice "Purpose" section at 47.1, which says it implements PL 95-202 and

  > Directs the Secretary of the Air Force to determine if an established group of **civilian employees or contract workers** provided service to the U.S. Armed Forces in a manner considered active military service for Department of Veterans Affairs (VA) benefits.

  Also, its title is "Active duty service for civilian or contractual groups." Members of the National Guard are not civilians. It would be *surprising* (to say the least) if they fell under this part, given that the clear purpose is to say "some civilian service to the military is not just a normal civilian job; these people deserve benefits given to people who are formally in the military."
- Surrounding rules. For instance, the definitions in 47.3 require that a group, to be a "civilian or contractual group" within the meaning of the part, be similarly situated to the Women's Air Forces Service Pilots.
- Statutory authority. All parts of the CFR need to be made under authority granted by Congress; the authority for 32 CFR 47 is a federal law codified as a note to 38 USC § 106 (and passed as PL 95-202 § 401(a)) saying

  > the service of any person as a member of the Women’s Air Forces Service Pilots (a group of Federal civilian employees attached to the United States Army Air Force during World War II), or the service of any person in any other similarly situated group the members of which rendered service to the Armed Forces of the United States in a capacity considered civilian employment or contractual service at the time such service was rendered, shall be considered active duty for the purposes of all laws administered by the Secretary of Veterans Affairs [if they meet DoD regulations to qualify for it]

  Administrative agencies are given a great deal of deference when interpreting the statutes they base their regulation on; however, they can't really *not* require that a group be similarly situated to WASPs, because the statute they're saying groups can qualify under *requires* that groups be similarly situated to qualify.

To answer your question about whether the National Guard gets benefits: Members of the National Guard are simultaneously members of the Army or Air Force reserves. This regulation lets certain *civilian* groups count as active duty, leaving it up to DoD who qualifies. For the military, there's no need to leave it up to DoD who qualifies; Congress is quite capable of simply defining what the military is. Under 38 USC § 101(21), "active duty" means, among other things, "full-time duty in the Armed Forces, other than active duty for training."

When the National Guard is on full-time military duty other than for training, they are on active duty, because that is what that phrase means. When they aren't, they aren't. At no point do they qualify because they are civilians in a similar situation to WASPs (which is the sole purpose of this part, to let those people qualify) due to their National Guard service; they are qualified because they are actually *in* the military, and not because some special policy means they qualify when they otherwise wouldn't.

Comment: So how would I challenge the agency interpretation?

Comment: For this? You can't. Your challenge would be laughed off, because it is incredibly obvious the regulation *doesn't* (and in fact *can't*) include the National Guard as a qualified group.

Comment: Then why would they call Military Sealift Command Navy because  "rendered service to the Armed Forces of the United States in a capacity considered civilian employment", when other civilians fall under Transportation, yet both are required to have a TWIC card, and DOT IDs.  To further delve in some are denied at MEPS, and  need to find a back door into the equivalent service by joining MSC to serve, and EEOC would administer the benefits then?

Comment: Where does anyone say MSC qualified under this part? All I find says they [only did in WWII](http://www.va.gov/vetapp10/files6/1045908.txt). Regardless, MSC is tied to the Navy because it is part of the Navy. MSC employees are mostly civilian, but they are employed by the US Navy. I'm not sure what this has to do with anything at all.

Comment: If MSC employees were just government mariners they would fall under the DOT, not Navy, but since they're Navy they're not contractors of the Navy, they're employees of the Navy, and get paid by the Navy, not DOT.

Comment: @acoder "If MSC employees were just government mariners they would fall under the DOT, not Navy" -- what? Why in the world would all government mariners have to fall under DOT? It's quite obvious they don't, because MSC *are* government civilian mariners, and *are* employed by the Navy. The Navy has a *lot* of civilian employees. And I'm not sure what 32 CFR 47 has to do with it.

Comment: 32 CFR 47 has to do with MSC CIVMARs, because in peacetime there is no armed conflict, and don't report to the Navy.

Comment: @acoder No, it doesn't, as far as I know; 38 CFR 3.7 has a list of groups that qualified under 32 CFR 47, and MSC isn't there. Merchant Mariners from WWII qualify. MSC has not been considered to qualify. They *do* report to the Navy (again, MSC is *part* of the Navy). In fact, since 47.4 requires service be rendered in a time of armed conflict, I'm not sure why you think it would apply to MSC in peacetime.

Comment: @acoder Hold on. Are you an ex-MSC member who is seeking veteran's benefits, arguing that it doesn't matter if MSC is similar to WASPs? Or are you forgetting the analysis on whether service is equivalent to military service? Or something else?

Comment: I'm "technically" still MSC saying that MSC is similar to WASP as both were civilian, and attached to the armed forces.  MSC can also do things that the normal Merchant Marine can't.

Comment: @acoder OK, so which of those conditions was the group application denied under? Or were they all accepted, but the judgment call of "is military-equivalent" came out against MSC?

Comment: MSC doesn't issue discharge papers for some reason, and if someone requests to quit it is normally granted.
MSC CIVMARs need to be comfortable with things like being around explosives on certain ships, and the military needs to be comfortable around them also.
I don't believe any CFRs came out against MSC receiving veterans status, but the Merchant Marine in general there has been, but it doesn't apply because MSC CIVMARs can receive service medals.

Answer (score 0):

Under the doctrine of *Chevron* Deference, when the law is ambiguous, the agency may interpret it in any way as long as it's reasonable. The courts usually interpret reasonableness as being almost anything.

Comment: Chevron deference is an agency interpreting a statute. Auer deference is an agency interpreting its own regulations.

Comment: Not entirely. The Supreme Court has expanded Chevron to cover interpretations as well.

Comment: What? Cheveron deference was always about interpretations. Auer v Robbins and Seminole Rock are the Supreme Court cases establishing deference to an agency regarding its own regulations.

Comment: Of topic because it's about the ambiguity of a law standing up in a court, but interesting to me none the less.

Comment: The agency can interpret it any way, but anyone can challenge their interpretation, and if there's a 50% chance (not beyond a reasonable doubt) they're wrong with their interpretation they need to pay up as with tort claims.

Comment: @acoder No, the standard is not 50% chance they're wrong. Courts give great deference to administrative agencies interpreting statutes, and even more to an agency interpreting their own regulation. Unless they are *clearly* incorrect, their interpretation wins.

Comment: @cpast Then doesn't the CFR need to be revised to say "must meet all"? How do you challenge a CFR interpretation?

Comment: @acoder It doesn't, because it's not even slightly ambiguous. You can't challenge the interpretation here, because their interpretation to require you be a civilian similarly situated to WASPs is both obviously correct and required by the statutory authority (they can't *not* require it).

Comment: @cpast That is still a wide open view, because it doesn't provide any requirements to be met.

Comment: @acoder What doesn't provide requirements? The statute, or the regulation? The statute requires you be like a WASP. The regulation provides a whole lot of requirements.

Comment: and all of those are met

Comment: @acoder By the Guard? No, very few are.